# Flow raises an error for a common pattern in React Native using bind()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, flowtype

In a React Native project, when passing event handler functions to the JSX components, you typically see this in the constructor if the project's using ES6:

```
handleSearch(input) { ... }

constructor() {
    // Other init logic...

    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
}
```

When I run the Flow type checker on this code, however, it gives me an error:

```
Cannot assign `this.handleSearch.bind(...)` to `this.handleSearch` because property `handleSearch` is not writable.

   33|         this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why? And what can I do to fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: Is your code written as it is over here? https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html. If so, than try copying the code from react documention into a new file and run flowtype on it, so that we can know where the problem is.

Comment: As a side-note, you can write functions with fat arrow: `handleSearch = () => { ... }` instead of `handleSearch() { ... }` to preserve the context of *this*. Thus binding in the constructor is not needed at all.

Answer (score 3):

As it says [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1517):

workaround is to do something like this in the constructor (the space after "this: " is important):

```
(this: any).myMethod = this.myMethod.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to type the methods at the class level:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6053#issuecomment-376716872

Something like that:

```js
class Mycomponent {
  handleSearch: (input) => mixed; // your flow definition for the method

  constructor() {
    // Other init logic...

    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
  }

  handleSearch(input) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Yep, methods are typed covariant by default:
https://flow.org/blog/2016/10/04/Property-Variance/#covariant-by-default-method-types